# Find a match on a different sheet then replace a cell in that row

Tags: vba, excel, find, offset

I'm not a VBA expert so struggling to get this to work by recording macros investigation - I currently have no macro I'm working off as the one I tried seems to delete random cells

I have a range of data:

Column A-P and rows 5-54, in Sheet 1

I have two values in sheet 2, the search ID (C2) and the new input (F2)

I'd like to search Sheet 1 column A for the search ID (sheet 2, C2) then replace the value in column P of that row with the value in Sheet 2 F2.

The use of this is on a register of items that I want to change as on or off site (the register is sheet 1), the ID of the item that is moved is put in Sheet 2 C2, then F2 uses =vlookup to show the current status of the item, this is then changed using a drop down box and I'd like this update to be copied over to the old register to update it.

The rest of the formula would be to clear the change of location form and repopulate the vlookup into the F2 cell:

```
Sheets("Sheet 2").Select
Range("C2").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "HPC-RS-"
Range("F2").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R2C3,'Sheet 1'!R5C1:R54C16,15,FALSE),"""")"
```

Comment: You could do this pretty easily with the [`Range().Find()`](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/#How_to_do_a_Simple_Find) method to get the row and column of the ID on the first page so you can replace it with the new value

Answer (score 0):

Your "delete random cells" comment leads me to beleive that maybe you're not intentionally using R1C1 relative cell notation in your code, as opposed to "standard/absolute" A1 notation.

For example, `Range(F2)` refers to the cell at the intersection of column F and row 2, whereas `R4C2` refers to the cell 4 rows down and 2 columns to the right of "whatever cell is currently active".

Before recording a macro, you can enable/disable relative references with a button near the "record macro" button. (I'm on my phone so I can't double check the button...)

> A relative reference in an Excel macro means relative to the currently active cell. So use caution with your active cell choice — both when you record the relative reference macro and when you run it.

This page walks you through creating a demo of both types of macros: https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/recording-excel-macros-with-relative-references/